# Converting NVARCHAR to INT after SUBSTRING using CHARINDEX and LEN

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, substring, charindex

I am trying to join two tables using UI's but the UI in one of the tables has 'CLIENT_' before it. When trying to remove the 'CLIENT_' from the string and then compare the UI's I am getting the following error.

Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

When attempting to convert or cast the whole subquery to INT or FLOAT the same error occurs.

Has anyone got any ideas or know how I can code to get this working.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 69 AS 'FIELD_ID',
ENTITY_ID,
AD.WIP AS 'WIP'
FROM [WORKVIEW].[DBO].ENTITY_MASTER EM
JOIN [LIVE].[MHGROUP].PROJECTS P ON P.PRJ_ID = EM.ENTITY_PARENT 
JOIN [WORKVIEW].[DBO].adn_NAMEACCOUNTSDATA_STAGING AD ON 
CAST((SELECT SUBSTRING(P.CUSTOM1, CHARINDEX ('_', P1.CUSTOM1) -1, LEN(P1.CUSTOM1)) 
FROM [IMAN-SQL].[LIVE].[MHGROUP].PROJECTS P1 
WHERE P.CUSTOM1 LIKE 'CLIENT_%') AS INT) = AD.NAMENO
```

I would like to be able to join NAMEACCOUNTSDATA_STAGING on P.CUSTOM1 and AD.NAMENO as these are the only fields I can join these tables together with.

LATEST ATTEMPT AT MAKING THIS WORK....

```
SELECT DISTINCT 69 AS 'FIELD_ID',
ENTITY_ID,
AD.WIP AS 'WIP'
FROM [WORKVIEW].[DBO].ENTITY_MASTER EM
JOIN [IMAN-SQL].[LIVE].[MHGROUP].PROJECTS P ON P.PRJ_ID = EM.ENTITY_PARENT 
JOIN [WORKVIEW].[DBO].WORKVIEW_NAMEACCOUNTSDATA_STAGING AD ON CONCAT('CLIENT_', AD.NAMENO) = P.CUSTOM1 AND P.CUSTOM1 LIKE 'CLIENT_%'
```

Schema's for all three tables involved:

```
TABLE [dbo].[entity_master](
[entity_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[entity_parent] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[entity_child] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[entity_status] [int] NOT NULL,
[entity_child_name] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
[entity_parent_name] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
[GUID] [varchar](50) NULL,

TABLE [dbo].[WORKVIEW_NAMEACCOUNTSDATA_STAGING](
[NAMENO] [int] NOT NULL,
[WIP] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[BILLED] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[WRITTENOFF] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[DEBTORRESTRICTION] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[PAYMENTTERMS] [int] NULL,
[BILLING FREQUENCY] [nvarchar](max) NULL

TABLE [MHGROUP].[PROJECTS](
[PRJ_ID] [float] NOT NULL,
[PRJ_PID] [float] NULL,
[DEFAULT_SECURITY] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[IS_SECURED] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[PRJ_NAME] [nvarchar](254) NULL,
[PRJ_OWNER] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
[PRJ_DESCRIPT] [nvarchar](254) NULL,
[PRJ_STATE] [char](1) NULL,
[PRJ_PUBLIC] [char](1) NULL,
[PRJ_LOCATION] [nvarchar](254) NULL,
[TYPE] [int] NOT NULL,
[SUBTYPE] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
[INHERITS_SECURITY] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[DOCNUM] [float] NULL,
[VERSION] [int] NULL,
[CUSTOM1] [nvarchar](254) NULL,
[CUSTOM2] [nvarchar](254) NULL,
[CUSTOM3] [nvarchar](254) NULL,
[LEFT_VISIT] [int] NULL,
[RIGHT_VISIT] [int] NULL,
[TREE_ID] [int] NULL,
[EMAIL] [nvarchar](254) NULL,
[DOC_SAVED_SEARCH] [int] NULL,
[LAYOUT_NAME] [nvarchar](254) NULL,
[LAYOUT_ORDER] [int] NULL,
[LAYOUT_VIEW] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[REFERENCE_DATABASE] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
[REFERENCE_PRJ_ID] [float] NULL,
[REFERENCE_TYPE] [int] NULL,
[REFERENCE_SUBTYPE] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
[IS_EXTERNAL] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[EXTRNL_AS_NRML] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[IS_DOC_SVD_SRCH] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[IS_PRJ_SVD_SRCH] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[IS_HIDDEN] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[EDITWHEN] [datetime] NOT NULL,
```

Hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Is AD.NAMENO definitely an INT column? Please post some detail of the tables used with their datatypes (or at least the columns for the join)

Comment: Oh - and also tag in which flavour of SQL you are using (e.g. TSQL, MySQL, Postgre, etc)

Comment: Hi iainc, thanks for replying. I have included what you have asked. Hopefully this helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the *number* to a *string*!

```
(SELECT SUBSTRING(P.CUSTOM1, CHARINDEX ('_', P1.CUSTOM1) -1, LEN(P1.CUSTOM1)) 
 FROM [IMAN-SQL].[LIVE].[MHGROUP].PROJECTS P1 
 WHERE P.CUSTOM1 LIKE 'CLIENT_%'
) = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(254), AD.NAMENO)
```

Or:

```
(SELECT P.CUSTOM1
 FROM [IMAN-SQL].[LIVE].[MHGROUP].PROJECTS P1 
 WHERE P.CUSTOM1 LIKE 'CLIENT_%'
) = CONCAT('CLIENT_', AD.NAMENO)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I have tried both of these methods and neither overcome the error message of "error converting data type nvarchar to float". I have tried to apply your second idea using CONCAT without a sub query on the join but still getting the same error. I am really not sure why this wouldn't work. I have aded my latest attempt to my post above.

Comment: @AlexNewsum . . . Then the conversion problem is happening somewhere else in the query.

Comment: Oh my, you're right. I have just had another pair of eyes look at this and it was the P.PRJ_ID join on the PROJECTS table that was causing the issue! I have simply converted this to NVARCHAR and it works fine. Thank you for everyone's help as it got me there in the end!

Answer (score 0):

Did you test your substring? In my testing I get

***Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'T_1456' to data type int.***

So the substring is getting the charindex of the underscore then you are removing a character to get T_ which can't be converted to INT. Changing to plus in stead of minus gets a valid join.

```
CAST((SELECT SUBSTRING(P.CUSTOM1, CHARINDEX ('_', P1.CUSTOM1) +1, LEN(P1.CUSTOM1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I realise I definitely had a - instead of a +. However, I am still getting the same error - converting data type nvarchar to float. I have tried so many different variations of what you're suggesting with no luck.

Comment: can you post the data schema for the tables involved then. My modelling of your query worked without a problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help on this. I have posted the schema's for the three tables involved. I just cannot understand why this wouldn't work. Is it something else in the script?

Comment: I see Gordon beat me to it!